# How to refer to a current cell in a range when using conditional rules?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column of cells range(A2:A10) containing a date for the first day of each week.
I want the cell color to change when the date is in the past.

When I select the cells I can apply a conditional rule but I can't figure out how to write the formula so it applies to each individual cell.

For example:
formula
`=A2>TODAY()` 
works

However that rule will apply to the whole range returning the result for whether the date value in A2 is in the past.

I want the formula so that the value in A3 is the deciding factor for cell A3, A4 is the deciding factor for A4 etc..

The best way I can explain it would be using "this" in coding when writing the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select cells you want formatting in. For example `A2:A10`. When creating rule choose "Format only cells that contains" and in "Format only cells with:" choose "less than" and write `=TODAY()` formula:

[image]

Result:
[image]

Keep in mind that date format may be different due to settings.

Also tested your formula and it works fine:
[image]

Comment: That worked a treat. Thanks a lot.
I was obviously overthinking it myself!